# Pegar parte do valor do campo

Tags: javascript, html

ola,
preciso de pegar parte do valor do input

```js
function exibir(){

    var elem = document.getElementById("campo3").value; 
    var sel = document.getElementById("campo4").value;
            
     document.getElementById("demo1").value = elem+sel;
    
    
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Nova pagina 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_dadosdasolicitacao2" >
       
<div class="panel-body">

 <div class="row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-3"> 
        <label> Campos 1 </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo3" id="campo3" value="Contrato">
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="row">    
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
    <label> Campos 2 </label>   
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="Empresa">

 </div>
 </div> 
 
 <div class="row">   
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Junção </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo1" readonly>
 </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Resultado esperado </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo2" value="ConEmp">
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="exibir()" id="clicar">Gerar</button>
</div>
 </div>
       
         
       

</div>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Nesse exemplo ele copia os dois valores
eu queria mais ou menos assim:

um campo que aparece [ContratoEmpresa] apresentar no campo apenas os 3 primeiros valores do campo.
exemplo 
Resultado:
[ContratoEmpresa] 
aparecer
[ConEmp]

[image: Resultado Esperado]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, basta você utilizar [substr(0,3)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp). Este método funciona recebendo dois tipos de parâmetros:

- O primeiro parâmetro é o index inicial que você pegará da sua String, no caso, sendo o primeiro index `0`;
- O segundo é a quantidade de caracteres que você deseja extrair, que seria `3`;

Veja no seu código:

```js
function exibir(){

    var elem = document.getElementById("campo3").value; 
    var sel = document.getElementById("campo4").value;
             
     var resultado1 = elem + sel;
   var resultado2 = elem.substr(0, 3) + sel.substr(0, 3);

    document.getElementById("demo1").value = resultado1;
    document.getElementById("demo2").value = resultado2;
    
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Nova pagina 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_dadosdasolicitacao2" >
       
<div class="panel-body">

 <div class="row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-3"> 
        <label> Campos 1 </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo3" id="campo3" value="Contrato">
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="row">    
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
    <label> Campos 2 </label>   
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="Empresa">

 </div>
 </div> 
 
 <div class="row">   
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Junção </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo1" readonly>
 </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Resultado esperado </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo2">
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="exibir()" id="clicar">Gerar</button>
</div>
 </div>
       
         
       

</div>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Corrige ai,, a junção deve ser `ContratoEmpresa` no elemento de `id=campo3` e  `ConEmp`  no elemento de `id=campo4 `

Comment: Não entendi @LeoCaracciolo. Esses campos são os inputs dos nomes `Contrato` e `Empresa`, respectivamente, não? O que eu entendi é que o usuário queria que o resultado no campo `demo1` fosse igual ao do `demo2`. Porém, independente dessa ambiguidade o resultado final é o mesmo.

Comment: No seu resultado esperado o que aparece é o value já existente e ele quer o resultado de substring

Comment: Acho que a imagem postada confundiu tudo. No código há os dois inputs

Comment: Ah!! Agora já foi! :) , mas como disse, o aprendizado foi o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

> O método `substr(inicio[, quantos])`. `inicio` um inteiro entre 0 e o  comprimento da string, especificando a posição na string do primeiro caractere a ser incluído na substring retornada. O segundo são quantos itens irá retornar à partir do índice informado no primeiro parâmetro

```js
function exibir(){

 var elem = document.getElementById("campo3").value; 
 var sel = document.getElementById("campo4").value;
      
      var res = elem.substring(0, 3);
      var res2 = sel.substring(0, 3);
            
 document.getElementById("demo1").value = elem+sel;
       
 document.getElementById("demo2").value = res+res2; 
    
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Nova pagina 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_dadosdasolicitacao2" >
       
<div class="panel-body">

 <div class="row" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-3"> 
        <label> Campos 1 </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo3" id="campo3" value="Contrato">
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="row">    
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
    <label> Campos 2 </label>   
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="Empresa">

 </div>
 </div> 
 
 <div class="row">   
 <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Junção </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo1" readonly>
 </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group  col-md-3"> 
 <label> Resultado esperado </label>      
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo2" value="">
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="exibir()" id="clicar">Gerar</button>
</div>
 </div>
       
         
       

</div>

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @dvd acho que vc está vendo coisas imaginarias kkk

Comment: Verdade. Juro que vi rss

Answer (score 0):

Além do método `substring` das outras respostas, pode-se usar [`match`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) com uma expressão regular:

```
^\w{3} -> pega somente os 3 primeiros caracteres da string
```

Assim como o `substring`, o `match` é um método do ECMAScript 1, portanto também compatível com todos os navegadores.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function exibir(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("campo3").value; 
   var sel = document.getElementById("campo4").value;
      
   var elem3 = elem.match(/^\w{3}/);
   var sel3 = sel.match(/^\w{3}/);
   
   document.getElementById("demo1").value = elem+sel;
   document.getElementById("demo2").value = elem3+sel3; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_dadosdasolicitacao2">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
               <label> Campos 1 </label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo3" id="campo3" value="Contrato">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
               <label> Campos 2 </label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campo4" id="campo4" value="Empresa">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
               <label> Junção </label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo1" readonly>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
               <label> Resultado esperado </label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="demo" id="demo2" value="">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="exibir()" id="clicar">Gerar</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```